# Next js how to use Server Actions with Pages Routing Structure

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am pretty new to next.js. I know how to use server actions to submit forms through action. I used to do this in the `App` directory based routing system but for a project I have to work on `Pages` Directory based routing. now I am facing some issues doing that. **Is it even possible to implement that server action form submitting using this structure? if yes then how?**

I used this code inside Pages/old/index.tsx

```js
// Pages/old/index.tsx

const Page = () => {
  async function handleSubmit(data: FormData) {
    "use server";

    console.log(data.get("name"));
  }

  return (
    <form action={handleSubmit}>
      <input type="text" name="name" />
      <input type="number" name="age" />
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

and It's generating error :

```
./pages/old/index.tsx
Error: 
  x "use server" functions are not allowed in client components. You can import them from a "use server" file instead.
   ,-[C:\Users\tyson\Desktop\demo\pages\old\index.tsx:1:1]
 1 |     const Page = () => {
 2 | ,->   async function handleSubmit(data: FormData) {
 3 | |       "use server";
 4 | |   
 5 | |       console.log(data.get("name"));
 6 | `->   }
 7 |     
 8 |       return (
 8 |         <form action={handleSubmit}>
   `----
```

Same code works properly for App Dir based routing but not here. Thank You in Advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server actions is an experimental feature available only in the app router, so it’s not expected to work under the pages directory.

Comment: Yes I also just found that. Thanks Though.

Answer (score 1):

The pages/ directory based routing does not support server actions.

Server actions is an experimental feature available in Next.js version 13.4, on the app/ directory and is a **server side feature**.

Here is a reference:
https://nextjs.org/blog/next-13-4

It's also worth noting that if you would like to use the server actions in Next.js version 13.4, you will need to add it in your next.config.js

```
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    serverActions: true,
  },
};
```